# Averaging Mean & Standard Deviation of Rolling Time Frame

Tags: standard-deviation, moving-window

I have a data set of investment returns from Jan 2010 to Dec 2022.

I've also calculated the average return and standard deviation of this data set within a rolling time frame of 3 years, with 1 month window.

I.e.
Jan 2010 to Dec 2013: Average return A, SD A
Feb 2010 to Jan 2014: Average return B, SD B
Mar 2010 to Feb 2014: Average return C, SD C
...
Jan 2019 to Dec 2022: Average return K, SD K

I assume to calculate the average of this set of average returns (A, B, C..), I could take an arithmetic mean of them.

How do I go about calculating the average of this set of standard deviations? Do I also take an arithmetic mean?

I a formula on another website that goes like this

Average standard deviation = √ (SD A^2 + SD B^2 + SD C^2 + … + SD K^2) / k
where K is the number of data set.

Is this formula correct? or should I be using the median return and standard deviation instead?